# Installing Android SDK Components

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

Help me with getting started with Android Studio...
I have just installed Android studio Bundle (nearly 850 mb).
Than I installed some SDK components as shown in pic...
[image]

After I start android studio and compile default source code
I get this: [image]

Then when I execute it it shows this:
[image]

How do I get Proper Out put?

Comment: whats the version of android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is striking through ActionBarActivity Class because this class is deprecated. AppCompatActivity is used instead since version 22.1.0. More infos here : http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html and here : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

For the output on your emulator, it takes time to start and emulate as android. You should be patient. :) Personnaly, I've never succeeded in running the android emulator on my Windows machine. I always got output just like you. But when I installed android studion on my Linux machine, it just took me something like 2-5 minutes the first time I launched it. So you know now what you have to do. :)

Comment: TNX Bro....
I solved ActionBarActivity deprecated error... bt hw long i should wait to get the output .. Almost i waited fr 10 min

Comment: Glad you solved your errors now @Deepak :). In order to make the Android emulator run faster and be more responsive, you can configure it to take advantage of hardware acceleration, using a combination of configuration options, specific Android system images and hardware drivers. Read the how-to here http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm to know how to configure and use hardware acceleration on your Windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Its emulator, it might take some time to start and emulate as android.
When emulator is read then your application will be executed as application not as console until you use android API for sending log output like "Log.d()" .

You should start training and follow guide from android's site : http://developer.android.com/training/index.html